How to remotely start program and exit?
I want to start gui program over ssh and close the connection after start leaving program to run on remote. Program need to be run on specific path (/home/pi/ISKRA), and program is python (tkinter) script named GUI.py
I try with:
ssh pi@192.168.64.129 "cd /home/pi/ISKRA; DISPLAY=:0 nohup ./GUI.py & exit"

The program is started as should be, the problem is that I need to press CTRL-C to terminate ssh session. Otherwise I got all output from remote system in local console. Seems that

& exit

isn't executed at all.

Got it working with script.
On remote I write script guirun:
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/ISKRA
export DISPLAY=:0
nohup ./GUI.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &

started on my computer with
ssh pi@192.168.64.129 "/home/pi/ISKRA/guirun"


maybe tell your program to expect no input by typing </dev/null before & exit
reference: What is </dev/null in bash?
by cmh:

Redirecting /dev/null to stdin will give an immediate EOF to any read
call from that process. This is typically useful to detach a process
from a tty (such a process is called a daemon). For example, when
starting a background process remotely over ssh, you must redirect
stdin to prevent the process waiting for local input.

I am not sure tho that this is the problem!

That doesn' work

seems that  2>&1 & is essential
